# How do I write this UPDATE SQL statement in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

So this query, after some assistance from user |sticky bit| works beautifully, but now I can't quite work out how to translate it into a Laravel Eloquent structure.

```
    UPDATE knowns
        SET engagementtitle = (SELECT instructions.engagementtitle
                                 FROM instructions
                                 WHERE instructions.reference = knowns.reference)
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM instructions 
                        WHERE instructions.reference = knowns.reference);
```

The part that I'm strugggling with is the non-obvious order in which the Eloquent statements are assembled.

I've tried the approach of getting the inner parts working, and then attempting to wrap them further. So the WHERE EXISTS clause can be created by this:

```
DB::table('knowns')
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
           $query->select(DB::raw('1'))
                 ->from('instructions')
                  ->whereRaw('instructions.reference = knowns.reference');
        })
        ->get();
```

Which produces

```
select * from "knowns" 
where exists (select 1 from "instructions" where instructions.reference = knowns.reference)"
```

But I'm not getting much further to wrap that part. For one, I'm unable to find in the documentation, an equivalent of the keyword "SET".

Here's my complete attempt to produce the SQL statement above.

```
DB::table('knowns')
->update(['instructions.reference' => 'knowns.reference'])
->select('instructions.engagementtitle')
->from('instructions')
->where('instructions.reference=knowns.reference')
->whereExists(function ($query) {
         $query->select(DB::raw('1'))
               ->from('instructions')
               ->whereRaw('instructions.reference = knowns.reference');
        })
->get();
```

(Apologies for the dog's breakfast - it even *looks* bad)

**EDIT:** 
Or I could just use a PDO approach like this....

```
$PDO=DB::connection()->getPdo();
$stmt=$PDO->prepare("
               ...SQL STATEMENT...
       ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But I'd still ike to know if there is an Eloquent approach.

Comment: Prepare relations and model firstly and then try to operate with eloquent

Comment: I've thought about relations... but in this situation I don't think it's a good idea. The problem is that the Instructions can get refreshed at anytime, and I'm unsure about establishing a relationship with a dataset that is not static.?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://medium.com/@akaamitgupta/get-the-latest-record-on-the-group-in-the-most-eloquent-way-50597a588361

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your plain sql query using join like

```
UPDATE 
  knowns k 
  JOIN instructions i ON i.reference = k.reference
SET k.engagementtitle = i.engagementtitle
```

And in query builder i guess this should work

```
DB::table('knowns as k')
    ->join('instructions as i', 'i.reference', '=', 'k.reference')
    ->update(['k.engagementtitle' => DB::raw("i.engagementtitle")]);
```